# Using pandas to count value in sqlite table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I have a sqlite table called "word_table" shown below

| id | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hi |
| 1 | bye |
| 1 | hello |
| 2 | this |
| 2 | hello |
| 2 | this |
| 3 | that |
| 3 | how |

How do i use pandas to create a dataframe with the output below

| id | word | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi | 1 |
| 1 | bye | 1 |
| 1 | hello | 1 |
| 2 | this | 2 |
| 2 | hello | 1 |
| 3 | that | 1 |
| 3 | how | 1 |

It computes the number of times each word appears in each id and store it in a new column "count".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `.groupby()` + `.value_counts()`:

```py
df["count"] = df.groupby("id")["word"].transform(
    lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts())
)
print(df.drop_duplicates())
```

Prints:

```
   id   word  count
0   1     hi      1
1   1    bye      1
2   1  hello      1
3   2   this      2
4   2  hello      1
6   3   that      1
7   3    how      1
```